# MappedByteBuffer byte orders reversed?

Tags: java, matlab, bytebuffer

I have a java.nio.MappedByteBuffer that I am using to read integers from a little-endian file.  I set the byte order to LITTLE_ENDIAN using ByteBuffer.order(), but this causes the buffer to interpret integers as if they were big endian.

**Confirm that we have the number 3 in little endian in bytes 4-7**

```
>> sprintf( '%.2x ', qfunction.s_idx.get(4), qfunction.s_idx.get(5), qfunction.s_idx.get(6), qfunction.s_idx.get(7) )

ans =

03 00 00 00
```

**Reading as LITTLE_ENDIAN returns 0x03000000 instead of 0x00000003!**

```
>> qfunction.s_idx.order( java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN );
>> sprintf( '%.8x', qfunction.s_idx.getInt(1) )

ans =

03000000
```

**Reading as BIG_ENDIAN does return 3!***

```
>> qfunction.s_idx.order( java.nio.ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN );
>> sprintf( '%.8x', qfunction.s_idx.getInt(1) )

ans =

00000003
```

What is going on here?

Using Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
Using MATLAB R2011b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing bytes 4,5,6,7 but reading bytes 1,2,3,4.  This makes byte 4 (which is the only one with a value) appear at the end instead of the start,

Try instead

```
>> sprintf( '%.8x', qfunction.s_idx.getInt(4) )
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  To clarify for others, I was treating the argument of ByteBuffer.getInt() as if it were an index into an array of integers (1 = "I want the second integer) when its is really a byte offset.

Comment: Perhaps `IntBuffer ib = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();` is more to your liking. ;)